# VBA: how to color ComboBox conditionally?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a ComboBox colored in red :
[image]

[image]

I would like to change the color (on white) of this ComboBox when I chose the value, like this :

[image]

Is it possible please ?
Thank you !

Comment: Yes it is possible. Use the `ComboBox1_Click()` to change the color. For example `ComboBox1.BackColor = RGB(123, 224, 222)`

Comment: Are you talking about a worksheet combo of a Form one? If worksheet control, is it a `Form`, or an `ActiveX` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that you are referring to an ActiveX combo type, you should use its `Change` event, in the next way:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
     If Me.ComboBox1.value = "ABN AMRO FRANCE" Then
        Me.ComboBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     Else
        Me.ComboBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Marie: Glad I could help! But it should be good to answer our clarification questions. A Sheet form combo (DropDown, in fact) does not have a `BackColor` property and its value is differently returned...